# Which attributes affect pet damage in Grim Dawn?

Tags: grim-dawn

As always in a ARPG, I'm trying to build a summoner. I therefore chose Occultist and Shaman as classes. To me, apart from the obvious *+% to pet damage*, it's not clear to me what increases the damage of my pets.

Which attributes should I be looking at when choosing which pieces of armor to wear? Right now, I'm trying to keep everything that increases my DPS, but I have no idea if it increases my pet's DPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that affects pet damage is the 'bonus to all pets' stat that comes with certain equipment. If the pet is granted via an item, it will also scale based on player level. Other attributes don't matter. ([Source](http://grimdawn.wikia.com/wiki/Pets)) Also, certain pets like the [Wind Devil](http://grimdawn.wikia.com/wiki/Wind_Devil_(Skill)) will scale with your damage and not pet bonuses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does it mean that pets become pretty useless at later levels?

Comment: Well, I'd say the bigger problem is that most troublesome enemies you face will just go straight for you, ignoring your pets. I haven't played in months but a Conjurer was very OP back then - just keep running in circles and let your pets kill everything.